# When do programmers use code first approach?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc

This is just not related to asp.net mvc but rather related all the mvc frameworks that support code first approach. One of the advantages I often see on asp.net mvc and tutorial blogs is that it supports code first approach. I'm work as a .net consultant and on the various projects( old and new) I have never seen anyone use code first approach. Just because I didn't see doesn't mean does not mean people don't use code first approach. One of the main reasons my team never favored it is because stored procedures are faster than using orm like entity framework. I understand that code first approach will make writing data acess logic a little easier. from my expirence I would never use code first when I'm working on a complex project. By complex project I mean cross database queries and security rights etc. Am I right with my assumption? If so what kind of projects would one use code first approach?

Comment: Most websites are a skin over a database.

Comment: You might want to describe "code-first" as used by entity framework, as opposed to the other "code first" which many would consider "skip gathering any requirements and up-front design"

Comment: @jeffO sometimes, but it can be the other way round. Is the database key to your application, or do you just need to persist some. Net objects. You could probably replace a lot of code first DBs with (cheaper) object stores.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always use code first and would never think about data first unless I have to integrate with an existing database. Why?

1. Instead of starting by figuring out what database looks like, I start by figuring out what my application does.
2. I don't have to reconcile my up-front database design with the functionality, web pages, API's etc. Instead, I do all of the design activities together.
3. The cost of "pre design" can be high especially if something has changed in the overall goals of the application that causes the database model to change significantly.

Comment: This. Very nice summarization.+1

Answer (score 3):

If a team has:

- A DBA,
- Or a developer who is even slightly knowledgeable about databases,

then the team will be inclined to avoid code-first approach. This is the same as using WYSIWYG editors when your team knows HTML: while the job *can* be done with a WYSIWYG, you still need to do it by hand if you need decently written, maintainable code.

This has nothing to do with stored procedures in particular (and I find your claim about the performance overrated), but rather with the quality of the design itself. Of course, the number of features one can use (stored procedures, computed columns, FILESTREAM, etc.) matters too.

Another aspect to consider is that the database schema is just one of the aspects to consider for a fully-featured product. Another aspects could be the backup strategy, federation (load balancing) and the overall long-term maintenance of the server.

On the other hand, code-first approach is great:

- **For teams with no DBAs and no people who know how databases are designed.** They can either try to do it by hand (and fail), or let the tool do the job. Even if the tool won't do a great job, it will still be not much worse (or even better) compared to what an inexperienced programmer can do when designing a database schema.
- **For tiny projects.** If I am doing my personal website which will be used by me and a few of my friends, there is really no need to use indexes or chose carefully how tables are linked together. Any design (or lack of thereof) will work.
- **For prototypes.** The goal is not to do well, but to do fast. If code-first approach means that you can finish the feature in six hours instead of seven, this is a great benefit. This is where code generators (including ones which produce lousy code) or code-first ORMs are particularly valuable: they let you to craft a thing very quickly and focus on the details which matter (the object of a prototype) by abstracting the details which don't (the database schema).

Comment: Putting poorly written sql in a stored procedure doesn't improve the performance nor will it over-come a bad design.

Comment: This just reads like a rant along the lines of "code-first isn't doing it properly".

Comment: @JuliaHayward: it's not. The last part of the answer lists the perfectly valid cases where skilled teams will use code-first approach. The first part makes the OP aware of the possible drawbacks of code-first approach for large projects. The goal was to have a complete and neutral comparison (not provided by the other answers, by the way). I'm not sure how this can be interpreted as a rant. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is a rant. I have heard some of the issues @MainMa raised when I was talking to senior developers who were against code first. Would have upvoted but don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The basic thing to grasp is that code relates to a single use case whereas data can relate to several use cases.

So while code first is good for a simple system with a few use cases anything complex with multiple use cases is going to need a decent data model to ensure that all use cases are covered.